# Parsing Json data in c# to convert to xml

Tags: c#, xml, json, linq

In my asp.net application , I have to pass data in xml format to stored procedure.

The data which I have is in format of Json as below:

```
{
  "total": 10,
  "page": 1,
  "records": 100,
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "cell": [
        "217121",
        "1001",
        "CAMRY",
        "2532",
        "2532",
        "0",
        "36",
        "8",
        "13",
        "0.03",
        "0.15",
        "0.15",
        "0.10",
        "0.14"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "cell": [
        "217121",
        "1001",
        "CAMRY",
        "2540",
        "2540",
        "0",
        "6",
        "18",
        "13",
        "0.29",
        "0.14",
        "0.14",
        "0.21",
        "0.27"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "cell": [
        "217121",
        "1001",
        "CAMRY",
        "2546",
        "2546",
        "0",
        "9",
        "3",
        "5",
        "0.13",
        "0.35",
        "0.35",
        "0.24",
        "-0.32"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "cell": [
        "217121",
        "1001",
        "CAMRY",
        "2548",
        "2548",
        "0",
        "29",
        "8",
        "14",
        "0.30",
        "0.16",
        "0.16",
        "0.23",
        "-0.41"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "cell": [
        "217121",
        "1001",
        "CAMRY",
        "2550",
        "2550",
        "0",
        "31",
        "17",
        "7",
        "0.12",
        "0.10",
        "0.10",
        "0.11",
        "-0.14"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "cell": [
        "217121",
        "1001",
        "CAMRY",
        "2554",
        "2554",
        "0",
        "20",
        "37",
        "3",
        "0.13",
        "0.10",
        "0.10",
        "0.11",
        "-0.62"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In my button click I want to parse this and convert this to xml. I am using namespace

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

And used following code,

```
protected void TEST_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var modelJson = hdnModelObject.Value;
    var obj=JObject.Parse(modelJson);
}
```

But not sure how to loop it. stuck in this line. Will be great if any suggessions.
Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you can read from [documentation on Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm)

**DeserializeXmlNode**

> The second helper method on JsonConvert is DeserializeXmlNode(). This
>   method takes JSON text and deserializes it into a XmlNode.
>
> *Because valid XML must have one root element the JSON passed to
>   DeserializeXmlNode should have one property in the root JSON object.
>   If the root JSON object has multiple properties then the overload that
>   also takes an element name should be used. A root element with that
>   name will be inserted into the deserialized XmlNode.*

There is a problem with your json, you need to add a one root element, so you could do something like this [.NETFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tJ25SV):

This is your current json in string format:

```
var json =
            @"{""total"":10,""page"":1,""records"":100,""rows"":[{""id"":0,""cell"":[""217121"",""1001"",""CAMRY"",""2532"",""2532"",""0"",""36"",""8"",""13"",""0.03"",""0.15"",""0.15"",""0.10"",""0.14""]},{""id"":1,""cell"":[""217121"",""1001"",""CAMRY"",""2540"",""2540"",""0"",""6"",""18"",""13"",""0.29"",""0.14"",""0.14"",""0.21"",""0.27""]},{""id"":2,""cell"":[""217121"",""1001"",""CAMRY"",""2546"",""2546"",""0"",""9"",""3"",""5"",""0.13"",""0.35"",""0.35"",""0.24"",""-0.32""]},{""id"":3,""cell"":[""217121"",""1001"",""CAMRY"",""2548"",""2548"",""0"",""29"",""8"",""14"",""0.30"",""0.16"",""0.16"",""0.23"",""-0.41""]},{""id"":4,""cell"":[""217121"",""1001"",""CAMRY"",""2550"",""2550"",""0"",""31"",""17"",""7"",""0.12"",""0.10"",""0.10"",""0.11"",""-0.14""]},{""id"":5,""cell"":[""217121"",""1001"",""CAMRY"",""2554"",""2554"",""0"",""20"",""37"",""3"",""0.13"",""0.10"",""0.10"",""0.11"",""-0.62""]}]}";
```

This is your json string wrapped in a root element:

```
var jsonWithRoot = string.Format("{{'root': {0}}}",json);
```

This is your XMLDocument:

```
XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonWithRoot);
```

Console Application example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;


public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        var json =
            @"{""total"":10,""page"":1,""records"":100,""rows"":[{""id"":0,""cell"":[""217121"",""1001"",""CAMRY"",""2532"",""2532"",""0"",""36"",""8"",""13"",""0.03"",""0.15"",""0.15"",""0.10"",""0.14""]},{""id"":1,""cell"":[""217121"",""1001"",""CAMRY"",""2540"",""2540"",""0"",""6"",""18"",""13"",""0.29"",""0.14"",""0.14"",""0.21"",""0.27""]},{""id"":2,""cell"":[""217121"",""1001"",""CAMRY"",""2546"",""2546"",""0"",""9"",""3"",""5"",""0.13"",""0.35"",""0.35"",""0.24"",""-0.32""]},{""id"":3,""cell"":[""217121"",""1001"",""CAMRY"",""2548"",""2548"",""0"",""29"",""8"",""14"",""0.30"",""0.16"",""0.16"",""0.23"",""-0.41""]},{""id"":4,""cell"":[""217121"",""1001"",""CAMRY"",""2550"",""2550"",""0"",""31"",""17"",""7"",""0.12"",""0.10"",""0.10"",""0.11"",""-0.14""]},{""id"":5,""cell"":[""217121"",""1001"",""CAMRY"",""2554"",""2554"",""0"",""20"",""37"",""3"",""0.13"",""0.10"",""0.10"",""0.11"",""-0.62""]}]}";


          var jsonWithRoot = string.Format("{{'root': {0}}}",json);
          XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonWithRoot);

          using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
           using (var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
           {
             doc.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);
             xmlTextWriter.Flush();
             Console.Write(stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
           }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use JArray to parse your json string, and iterator the array.

```
JArray a = JArray.Parse(json);
foreach(var obj in a) {
    //iterator the array
}
```